# How to place jar files ahead of SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

We are moving our years old Android project to Android Studio and away from eclipse.

The problem is that we have some jar files that use code specific to the devices that we work on. (I know! Don't say it. I'm working with the whole team to move past this.) Since these JAR files override some of the bluetooth code, they have to go ahead of the SDK in the dependency list for the thing to build. (These libraries are for compile time only.)

While on eclipse, Android SDK was a full blown plugin and I could control the libraries absolutely and make sure these libraries were first. With Android Studio, I don't seem to be able to control the position of the SDK in the dependency path.

I have edited the app.iml file and changed the order of the orderEntry tags at the bottom. This appears to have fixed the problem inside the IDE and it appears to be building fine now.

I am still unable to build the project using gradle.

Based on feedback here, here is my current build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations { razrBuild }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    razrBuild fileTree(dir:'assets',include: ['*.jar'])
    provided files('assets/BluetoothGattService.jar')
    provided files('assets/BluetoothGatt.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/myapp-util.jar')
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    project.android.applicationVariants.all { v ->
        v.javaCompile.classpath += configurations.razrBuild
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put jars you want to compile time only into a folder(For my example : extlib)
Then add some configurations to build.gradle

```
configurations { providedCompile }

dependencies {
      providedCompile fileTree(dir:'extlib',include:['*.jar'])  
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    project.android.applicationVariants.all { v ->
        v.javaCompile.classpath += configurations.providedCompile
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed my build.gradle according to your comments and am still getting the same results at build time. I have posted the new build.gradle in my question.

Comment: Can you provide error messages after you excute "gradle assembleDebug"